# Methods to find $f$, given the functions $f \circ g$ and $g$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, elementary-functions

There is one way, which is to use the fact that $ \ f(g(g^{-1}(x)))=f(x)$. But this method only works if $g$ has a right inverse. There are other heuristic methods, which is to "guess the shape" of $ \ f$, given the composite function.

But is there a more powerful method that can be profitably used by non-calculus students? What about methods from calculus?

I ask this because the Malaysian public exams ask these questions a whole lot, and students normally jump right into these so-called "find the outside function" questions by assuming that $g$ is invertible, and then get into a knot when it's not.

Comment: Actually the method you suggested does not need an inverse for $g$, but a right inverse. So if $g$ is onto, you can construct a right inverse $h$ for $g$ and then calculate $f\circ g\circ h = f$. And also if $g$ is not onto, then this $f$ is not even unique.

Comment: Normally it's impossible to find $f$ knowing only $f\circ g$ and $g$.

Comment: For some $t$ with $g'(t) \neq 0$, you could try to taylor expand using the parametric derivatives where $x(t) = g(t)$ and $y(t) = f(g(t))$

Comment: @Levent Right, edited my post.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ polynomial, or rational function or something? If $f\circ g(x)=g(x)=\sin(x) $ then f(x) is not unique.

Comment: @user202729 I think we'd have to do with onto $g$'s.

Answer (score 0):

You can try letting $y=g(x)$, and finding an expression for $f(y)$.

Example:

$fg(x)=x^2+2$, $g(x)=x-1$.

Let $y=x-1$. Hence $x=1+y$.
Thus $fg(x)=f(y)=(1+y)^2+2=y^2+2y+3$.

Thus $f(x)=x^2+2x+3$.

Comment: Isn't $x=1+y$ exactly the inverse of $y=x-1$?